# Matlab, fread and sscanf for reading prefixed integers

Tags: matlab

I know this type of problem has been discussed plenty before, but I seem to miss out on how to properly solve it in my case...

I have some txt files with hundreds of thousands of lines of prefixed integers. Each line has 3 integers and each integer is prefixed with a single character, A, B, or C like so:

```
A25723B520C4
A25732B477C4
A25742B432C5
A25752B385C10
A25763B340C10
```

I'd like to have Matlab read the entire txt file into memory and use `sscanf` to give me a matrix with 3 columns and as many rows as there are lines in the txt file.

I've got it working if I use `textscan` (although it gives me a cell array), but I'd like to see if `sscanf` might be a bit faster - however, I can't seem to get the proper output from `sscanf`. Could someone kindly show me how to write an implementation based on `sscanf`in this case?

Here's what I have, based on `textscan`:

```
fid=fopen('sampleData.txt','r');
s = fread(fid,'*char')';
fclose(fid);
data = textscan(s,'%*c %d %*c %d %*c %d');
```

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Can you post that text file somewhere?  I've got a possible solution but I want to see if it will work with actual data.

Comment: Certainly! 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21384613/sampleData.txt

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I need to go at the moment, but will check back later...

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, I really appreciate your quick and thorough response! Marked as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for being quick :) You're very welcome. Let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did with `sscanf`.  Let's read in the text file like you did before with `fopen` and `fclose`.  After, we can use `sscanf` to look for a 6 token sequence:

> A character, followed by a number, followed by a character, followed by a number, followed by a character, then again followed by a number.

Given your example you gave above, this is what you would do with `sscanf`.

```
data = sscanf(s, '%c%d%c%d%c%d\n');
```

We need the `\n` delimiter in the end as there is a new line that separates each row of data.  Now, if you display `data`, this is what it looks like:

```
data =

      65
   25723
      66
     520
      67
       4
      65
   25732
      66
     477
      67
       4
      65
   25742
      66
     432
      67
       5
      65
   25752
      66
     385
      67
      10
      65
   25763
      66
     340
      67
      10
```

You'll see that the characters (A, B, or C) have been converted to their ASCII equivalents.  However, the numbers have been successfully parsed.  Following the convention that you have in your text file, you see that the numbers that go after A, B or C fall in the even positions of the text file.  For example, the A numbers start at position 2, and you need to **skip** over 6 to go to the next number for A as there were 6 things we read in for one line.  For the B numbers, we start at position 4 and for the C numbers we start at position 6.

As such, here's my way of splitting up the data and finally placing all of the numbers into a single matrix.

```
lengthData = length(data);
Acol = data(2:6:lengthData);
Bcol = data(4:6:lengthData);
Ccol = data(6:6:lengthData);
dataMatrix = [Acol Bcol Ccol];
```

... and this is what I get:

```
dataMatrix =

   25723         520           4
   25732         477           4
   25742         432           5
   25752         385          10
   25763         340          10
```